# Is there a single word that means "to add an amount to a running total"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm trying to determine what word would best be used to indicate an instruction to, when someone comes across a number of things in a given situation, add the number there (maybe written, or it may require counting a number in that situation) to a running total of similar things.

- It would be similar in usage to *count* or *tally*, but would specifically imply that there is more than one to add to the running total
- Something more similar in meaning to *accumulate* or *aggregate* except we're just tracking the numbers of things (like rocks or plants), not actually collecting them in a bag or box, so I'd prefer to avoid those words, which have that potential meaning
- *Add* might be close, but there's a reason the phrase "add to the running total" isn't just "add"
- Whereas *count* and *tally* and even *sum*, I think, imply "determine a number and report it", I want something that is more like "determine the number of these and then add that to this total"
- So, it would fit in this sentence in place of *accumulate*: "If you come across some hair pins, accumulate them in the 'sharp' count and the 'metal' count, but if you find buttons, they should be accumulated in the 'round' count - if they're round - and the 'flat' count."
- The more precise meaning of that sentence above is: "If you come across some hair pins, count them and add that number to the 'sharp' count and the 'metal' count, but if you find buttons, they should be counted and that total should be added to the both the 'round' count and the 'flat' count."

Comment: How about "increment"?

Comment: "increment by" would be a good meaning -- if given a straight number -- but doesn't to my knowledge have the WHOLE "_count_ and add to" meaning and it would be two words... obviously if I can't figure out a single word, I'll have to consider compound words, though

Comment: Could one not say "*increment* the running total", as suggested by @HotLicks? That's just only word. It's implicit that one has to determine the size of increment first and then simply add it to the running total.

Comment: @RichardKayser -- in my understanding, _1_ is implicit as the increment unless stated otherwise, so "increment the running total by 10" or "increment the total by that number" - it actually may be applicable enough to my usage, but I'm not sure if it's the best answer to my question (again, _if_ there is one)

Comment: The increment need not be *1*. It could be anything you want it to be. It's sound mathematical language.

Comment: One more thought. One could argue that *increment* captures both "the result of the tallying process" (noun) *and* "the action of adding that tally to the running total" (verb). If this is of some interest to you, you might want to consider encouraging @HotLicks to convert his comment into an answer.

Comment: "Include them in the sharp count" seems natural to me.

Answer (score 1):

***Tally*** the number of like items encountered and add that number to the **running total** in each of the clusters to which the items belong.

In coding terms:

*x = x + y*

where *x* is the running total and *y* is the tally

Comment: It doesn't appear to me that *tally* as you've defined it means *add an amount to a running total*. Is it not the amount to be added?

Comment: @RichardKayser: *tally* means count up the hairpins. Add that number -- that tally -- to the running total. Add a tally to a running total for a new running total.

Comment: I understand, but the OP is asking not for the tally, but for the verb that corresponds to adding the tally to the running total.

Comment: @RichardKayser: Yes, you just said it: *add to*. The OP's premise is a bit skewed, in my opinion; it's not the operation that needs clarifying, but rather the operator and the operand.

Comment: @TinfoilHat - I'm hoping to find a single word that means "tally and add to", if one exists

Answer (score 0):

How about **update**? M-W:

> **[update](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/update)**: bring up to date

When you add an amount (number) to a running total, you are **updating** the running total. For example, Johns Hopkins University regularly updates the number of confirmed cases and deaths due to Covid-19 in countries around the world. It's implicit that one has to determine the size of increment first (in my example, the number of new confirmed cases and deaths in a given time period) and then simply add it to the running total for all previous time periods.

Comment: _update_ isn't perfect, because it doesn't really have the explicit "Assess/count the number of new constituents" part of the meaning I'm looking for, but it's close, so it might be the best candidate for an answer so far!